# ASp.Net MVC routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC 2.0 to create my application,my problem i s related to the routing.
  Actually in my application each user have required seperate subdomain,like www.example.com/user1/    ,www.example.com/user2/  ...etc.the default domain is www.example.com.So how can i make it possible with routing in mvc.
 i have tried like this,

```
 routes.Add(new Route(
   "{id}", 
   new RouteValueDictionary(
       new { controller = "User", action = "login", id = " " }
   ), new MvcRouteHandler()));

   var defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(
      new
      {
           controller = "Home",
           action = "Index",
           id = UrlParameter.Optional

      }
   );

   routes.Add(new Route(
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults, 
    new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

But the problem is that it take deafult (www.example.com) directly to user login page.I want the default page as Home/index and when www.example.com/user1/ it will go to user login  page.Is there any way ..pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map a specific route for the home page.

```
routes.MapRoute("home","", new{controller="Home",action="Index"});
routes.MapRoute("users", "{username}/{action}", new { controller = "Users", action = "Login",username="" });
```

Comment: Hi Mika Kolari,
          Thanks For your answer very nice it is working.